# Handle Change of Multiselect choice field in SharePointusing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am testing out using SPUtility and jQuery to hide fields on a SharePoint 2013 form dynamically.  The demonstration solution I have recreated is found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88064/hide-show-field-on-list-form-based-on-value-from-another-field).  I am trying to modify it to trigger on change of a choice field allowing multiple selections (checkboxes).  The origional example is triggering off of changes to a choice field (dropdopwn) like this...

```
$(countryField.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
```

I have tried doing this...

```
$(country2Field.Checkbox).on('change', showOrHideField);
```

to no avail.  I suspect it is more complicated than I was hoping.

Comment: Did that worked for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use SPUtility, but you can do the same thing with jQuery, hope it works for you:

You can wrap your choices option in a div for example:

```
<div id="choicesPanel">
</div>
```

and by default apply the css `display:none`

```
<div id="choicesPanel" style="display:none">
    /*your choices elements*/
</div>
```

Now your choices options are hidden by default;

Then, you can add the code:

```
$(document).on('change', "#youDropdownId", function (){
     if($("#youDropdownId").val() == "DesiredOption"){
          $("#choicesPanel").show();
     }else{
          $("#choicesPanel").hide();
     }
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('change', "#youDropdownId", function (){
         if($("#youDropdownId").val() == "DesiredOption"){
              $("#choicesPanel").css("display", "block");
         }else{
              $("#choicesPanel").css("display", "none");  
         }
    });
```

So if the dropdown is changed and the value selected was your DesiredOption, it will show the choices;